# Programmatic license resolvement

Tags: java, rest, maven, licensing

Is there any possibility to distinguish license of an artifact by `artifactId:groupId:version` e.g. by accessing Maven repository via REST API?

Comment: P.S. I actually have to do that programmatically - without use of maven plugins.

Comment: Which Maven repository do you use? Nexus 2.x? Nexus 3.x? Artifactory?

Comment: internally Nexus 3, is it possible to use public repository instead(directly)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [Maven contentcheck plugin](http://code.kozelka.net/contentcheck-maven-plugin/show-licenses-mojo.html)?

```
mvn contentcheck:show-licenses
```

Comment: ty for your answer, however I already know some plugins that provide similar functionality. unfortunately I am not looking for a plugin, but for hint to my standalone solution.